# Codepen project will not deploy. SCSS doesn't load

Tags: javascript, css, sass, codepen

I have a codepen that works fine here:

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/abWvojK

As a project, scss will not deploy.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/project/live/AbamBJ

- I've routed the SCSS to index.html. Will it be automatically processed?
- The pen has CSS reset as a base. Could the be the source of the error?
- Console returns:

  Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-downloads' is an invalid sandbox flag.
  AbamBJ:32 Unrecognized feature: 'clipboard-read'.
  AbamBJ:32 Unrecognized feature: 'clipboard-write'.

Am I developing in the wrong version of Chrome? Mozilla Firefox returns the same errors. Neither browser is the latest build.

- JS console returns:

VM61 index.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at VM61 index.js:52

The start of the document uses standard, untouched codepen project boilerplate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My New Project!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Codepen projects. But by examining you code I see that your loaded CSS file is empty. So there must be some settings in your CP project that need to be fixed.

Comment: I checked on my browser [ Chorome ] it looks fine and no error.

Comment: My scss is loaded into index.scss. It's loaded into head as  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">. (this implies scss is auto-processed. I'm expecting the browser to automatically process the scss as index.processed.css. Is that wrong? I haven't changed any scss/bahaviour settings on the project. Working with the preset settings.

Comment: Amir Danish... just confirming.... the project (second link) loads fine, just the same as the pen? Maybe I should upgrade my Chrome version. Thanks.